Low-level call error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value $8099.91
Any ideas about this?
I am attempting to make a arbitrage swap using the following contract
The error is:
Low-level call error: err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x have 26389996078916648 want 3681518208500000000 (supplied gas 500000000)

3681518208500000000 is 3.1354971585ETH or $8099.91 @ 2583.29 $ Per Ether.
There obviously something wrong here with the the following code:
func gasCalculated(from, to, token string, amount int) *big.Int {
    // Fetch the contract ABI
    contractABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(flashLoanReceiverABI())) // Correct ABI fetching
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to fetch ABI:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }
    // Create context
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Fetch the base fee and gas tip (miner's tip) for the next block
    header, err := connection.Get().HeaderByNumber(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get header:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    tip, err := connection.Get().SuggestGasTipCap(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to suggest gas tip cap:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    // Increase the tip cap if it's too low (e.g., minimum 1 Gwei)
    minTipCap := big.NewInt(1000000000) // 1 Gwei
    if tip.Cmp(minTipCap) < 0 {
        tip.Set(minTipCap)
    }

    // Adding a margin of 2 Gwei to the base fee
    margin := big.NewInt(2000000000) // 2 Gwei

    // Calculate GasFeeCap by adding a margin to the base fee to ensure transaction inclusion
    gasFeeCap := new(big.Int).Add(header.BaseFee, margin)

    // Add the suggested gas tip cap to ensure priority in the transaction pool
    gasFeeCap.Add(gasFeeCap, tip)

    // Specify the sender and recipient addresses
    fromAddress := common.HexToAddress(from)
    toAddress := common.HexToAddress(to)
    tokenAddress := common.HexToAddress(token)

    addressType, err := abi.NewType("address", "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create address type: %v", err)
    }

    addresses := abi.Arguments{
        {Type: addressType},
        {Type: addressType},
        {Type: addressType},
    }

    packedData, err := addresses.Pack(fromAddress, toAddress, tokenAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to pack addresses: %v", err)
    }

    data, err := contractABI.Pack("onFlashLoan", fromAddress, tokenAddress, big.NewInt(int64(amount)), big.NewInt(0), packedData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ABI packing failed:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:      fromAddress,
        To:        &toAddress,
        GasFeeCap: gasFeeCap,
        GasTipCap: tip,
        Value:     big.NewInt(0), // Adjust if ETH is sent along with the call
        Data:      data,
    }

    // Perform the low-level eth_call to check the transaction
    var result hexutil.Bytes
    result, err = connection.Get().CallContract(ctx, callMsg, header.Number)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Low-level call %v\n", err) //<--Low-level call error: err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x have 26389996078916648 want 3681518208500000000 (supplied gas 500000000)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    // Decode or inspect `result` to understand the failure
    fmt.Printf("Low-level call result: %x\n", result)

    // Estimate the gas required for the transaction
    gasLimit, err := connection.Get().EstimateGas(ctx, callMsg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to estimate gas:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    return big.NewInt(int64(gasLimit))
}


your wallet account has thsi much :26389996078916648 but want this 3681518208500000000. obviously you do not have enough fund in your wallet account

Your are saying the transaction actually costs 3.68ETH?
